# How to return json data from endpoint within backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, backend

I am attempting to run a axios request through my front end to hit my backend, in which it will do a req.get to return a json object, this is what the axios code looks like:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:5000"
});


export const stockQuote = symbol => {
    return api.get(`/stock/${symbol}`);
}
```

and from that it will hit my backend which looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get(`/stock/:symbol`, async(req, res) => {
    const data = req.get(`https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/tops?token=Tsk_938206aef2a646dasdfe4ddf024b02f4&symbols=aapl`);
    console.log(data);
    res.send(data);
})

module.exports = router;
```

I want to work through my backend so the users cannot look at the specific api endpoints i am hitting, but for some reason the console.log(data) is returning undefined. What am i doing wrong here as im relitevly new to these features?

Edit: Here is my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
// const pool = require("./db");
const PORT = 5000;

//Parser for JSON objects passed through server
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

var iex = require('./routes/iex');


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Backend listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})

app.get(`/stock/:symbol`, iex);
```

Answer (score 0):

install body parser in your backed and access data like:

`const data = req.body`

and then

`console.log(data);`

Comment: I edited my post to give you more info, i have a parser in my main server.js, i tried to add the parser using router.use(express.js) and then data = req.body but it returned {} so im still doing something wrong.